# IOS Localization does not work on gluonhq/javafxports

Tags: gluon, javafxports

I am trying to use localization on @gluonhq using afterburner and it is working when deploying to Android, but does not work on IOS, the language and region setting works ok for other apps on IOS, but it does not take effect when opening my app.

It keeps english only.

Thanks!!

Comment: It should work just fine, post the relevant code so it can be reproduced.

Comment: ....

private ResourceBundle bundle;
    private Locale locale;

    private boolean editMode;

    public void initialize() {

        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("br.com.globalsuite.forceone.views.crm.crmprctarefaedit", Locale.getDefault());

...

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant code there, the build.gradle file, the FXML and the properties files if necessary

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://www.globalsuite.com.br/screen.png).

<VBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="300.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label text="%shortname" />
                                                <TextField fx:id="resumo" prefWidth="300.0" />
                                            </children>
                                        </VBox>


snippet from crmprctarefaedit_pt_BR ...

shortname=Resumo
stage=Etapa
collaborator=Colaborador

Comment: I noticed that even with the gluonhq components happens the same: 
[IOS](https://www.globalsuite.com.br/iosscreen.png).
[Android](https://www.globalsuite.com.br/androidscreen.jpeg).

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code there!

Comment: Which snippet of code you need to help?

Comment: Just read my comments, or see how to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want anyone to help you, you have to provide the required code so we can try and see what could be failing. For starters, build.gradle so we see the versions and dependencies you are using. Then a Presenter, the FXML and the properties files (not all the content, just a dummy property for instance), and any other detail you may consider relevant.

Comment: ok, but do you have an example on how to use "Locale" with the DatePicker component? Maybe I can solve the problem understanding that.